# Keep Checkbox Checked After Navigating Bewteen Partials

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm building a single page fantasy football application which has partial pages for each position and displays a list of players.

I want to implement a checkbox next to each player and as players get drafted I can check the checkbox and have a line go through that players name.

I'm having problems keeping the checkboxes checked as I navigate through the application. As I move through the pages the sate of the checkbox is lost. 
I'm not sure how to implement this in Angular.js.

Below is the code for my test application.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="RoutingApp">
    <h2>AngularJS Routing Example</h2>
    <p>Jump to the <a href="#first">first</a> or <a href="#second">second page</a></p>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**first.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Persist checkboxes</title>
    <style>
    button{
      margin-top:8px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>First Page</h1>
    <div>
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
    </div>

    <button>Check all</button>

   </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>

    <script>
      angular.module('app', [
        'ngStorage'
      ]).

      controller('Ctrl', function(
        $scope,
        $localStorage
      ){
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
          x: 42
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button ng-click="$storage.x = $storage.x + 1">{{$storage.x}}</button> + <button ng-click="$storage.y = $storage.y + 1">{{$storage.y}}</button> = {{$storage.x + $storage.y}}
  </body>

</html>
```

**routing script**

```
angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/first', {
                templateUrl: 'first.html'
            })
            .when('/second', {
                templateUrl: 'second.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made so many mistakes in your current code

Here I've mentioned few below.

1. Don't add full `html` inside your partial views. They should only mention required html.
2. Controller should be map to their views from route `controller` definition.
3. Use service/factory to share data between different controller.
4. Use dot rule when declaring `ng-model` that will help you to maintain [**prototypical inheritance**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

**Code**

```
angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/first', {
        templateUrl: 'first.html',
        controller: 'FirstCtrl'
      })
      .when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'second.html',
        controller: 'SecondCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);

angular.module('RoutingApp').controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
      x: 42
    });
  })
  .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, checkboxService) {
    $scope.model = checkboxService.data
  })
  .service('checkboxService', function() {
    var checkboxService = this;
    checkboxService.data = {
      option1: false,
      option2: false,
      option3: false
    };
  })
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mplubf0L2ZcGpJq1A4mX?p=preview)

Comment: The code that I posted was just examples that I copied off the internet to work with while I was learning how to do this. Thank your for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for.